# Expo problem. Unexpected token '{'. Import call expects exactly one argument

Tags: react-native, expo

Can't fix expo problem.
My package.json:

```
{"name": "smth", "version": "1.0.0", "main":  "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js", "scripts": {
"start": "expo start",
"android": "expo start --android",
"ios": "expo start --ios",
"web": "expo start --web" }, "dependencies": {
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.3.2",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.11",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.7.0",
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.4",
"expo": "~46.0.7",
"expo-app-loading": "~2.1.0",
"expo-linear-gradient": "~11.4.0",
"expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
"link": "^1.5.1",
"react": "18.0.0",
"react-dom": "18.0.0",
"react-native": "0.69.4",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "4.3.1",
"react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
"react-native-svg": "12.3.0",
"react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
"react-redux": "^8.0.2",
"tailwindcss-react-native": "^1.7.10" }, "devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.18.6",
"@types/react": "~18.0.0",
"@types/react-native": "~0.69.1",
"@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
"tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
"typescript": "^4.6.3" }, "private": true}
```

I'm trying to launch my project, but this error keeps popping up, I can't find any information
Screenshot:

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nsy0V.png)
[Babel config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oPhy.png)

Comment: It just seems a syntax error. Share you code or just check that by yourself and see if there are any syntax errors. If using any code editor (like vs code), it would me much easier to find that

Comment: This is not a syntax error, I create a new project with the command: 'npx create-expo-app -t expo-template-blank-typescript', then I insert this package.json, I write npm i, launch the project, change the start text in app.tsx and this error appears

Comment: so what are the changes which you made to the app.tsx file, please share

Comment: i add plugin in my babel.config.js and i see this error

Comment: Please share the code where you are making the changes

Comment: How are you expecting anyone to solve this problem when you are not providing the relevant code anf files

Comment: What kind of plugin did you add?

Comment: I actually have the same issue. might create a post of my own with some example code if that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I fixed it by

- removing node_modules
- removing deps that were causing the issue from package.json (in my case - react-native-svg)
- installing those deps **NOT** through `npm install`, but through `expo install`. The difference is that expo may have some compatibility issues with some libraries and `expo install` gets the version that it's compatible with as opposed to the latest one

hope this helps :)
cheers